# Evaluation software and upgrade problems

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have been surfing through this site for answers and really just want confirmation that I have it right.  I am looking at buying a tablet with the Windows 7 Ultimate evaluation version on board.

- I realize I will have to install a full version eventually and when I do this, can I install any Windows 7 version or does it have to be the Ultimate version?
- Can I install the full version directly over the evaluation version or do I have to uninstall the evaluation version and install an earlier Windows version and then upgrade? (I don't have an earlier version disc).
- Will Ultimate sync OK with my Laptop Windows 7 Home Premium version?
- What sort of money am I looking at to upgrade when the evaluation version runs out?
- Would I be better to pay more and purchase a tablet with a full version on board?

Comment: You are asking several questions. This site works best if you ask one question at the time.

Answer (score 1):

I have **never** seen a **tablet** even running Windows 7, let alone the Ultimate version.
But there is no OEM operating system with "evaluation". They are legal, full version OEM software, which are registered (and activated usually).

So, if you manage to find such a *tablet*:

- You don't have to install anything.
- Again, you will have to full version by default.
- Uhm, not sure what do you mean by 'sync', but yes. They are fine together. Ultimate just comes with some extra business, enterprise features.
- Nothing again.
- You can't buy one without a *full version*. :)

Comment: It's like.. you can't find a laptop with just an evaluation copy of Windows. Sure, some of the softwares **are** not full. But those are different apps, like 60-day Office, a McAffee virus protection, and so on. That's just the usual OEM "scrap".

Comment: *> You can't buy one without a full version.* Sure you can: **(1)** go to India; **(2)** buy one with the Starter Edition; **(3)** come back.

Comment: If you surf around you will find tablets are available with windows 7 and also dual windows 7 and android.  Some seem to come with the evaluation version of windows and this is what is concerning me - what happens when the evaluation version runs out>

Comment: I'm sorry @Jenne, I just never seen anything like that. I mean... if they SAY it COMES with Windows 7... then that is the full version. (Legal thing I guess.) So ... before you order, just call the shop for confirmation. (OR make them sign a paper, so you can always bring back the machine.)

Comment: @Synetech: That's just sad. Started edition is just a rip-off in my opinion. (My sister had Starter on her netbook. For about an hour. :)) But again, a tablet is something different.